# For one who likes trading games like monopoly what's the closest 2-player game with similar dynamics?

Tags: monopoly, trading, substitutes

I've recently kindled my spouse's joy in board games but she has always enjoyed Monopoly as a child and tends to have that bias when selecting games.

We've played Carcassone and she genuinely enjoys it but is still looking for that trading like game mechanic but mostly in a two player setting. Are there any games that can be considered as such?

Monopoly is purely a chance-based game that involves trading and making money by earning rent and selling property. The main mechanic she tends to favor is the trading and money making. I'm not aware of two player trading games which involve some kind of score (like amount of money) to determine the winner. I would like to know if something like this exists and is worth buying/playing especially for two players.

Comment: This is not a true "recommendations" question. The difference is that it is a "close substitutes" question, which is much narrower. Which is why I voted to reopen. See my answer on the related meta question.

Comment: I'd try Easy Money.

Answer (score 1):

How about *Traders of Genoa*?

> This is a game of trading, wares, and negotiation. The players take
>   the roles of traders in Genoa in the 16th century. They fulfill
>   orders, deliver messages, and take ownership of buildings in the city.
>   Of course, this is not possible without the help of the other traders
>   - thus, the need for clever negotiation. And that can cost money and other valuable goods! The player who earns the most in the game is the
>   winner!

http://riograndegames.com/Game/200-Traders-of-Genoa

It's a fair amount more complex than Monopoly, but much less random and there's a lot more negotiation and trading involved. It plays with two, although it is better with more, much like Monopoly. It'll probably take about 90 minutes to play to completion with two.

Currently officially out of print, but you shouldn't have too much trouble tracking down a copy. It's sometimes known as "Genoa" rather than "Traders of Genoa" but it's the same game.